# Class file file corrupted in Loading error in android studio

Tags: android, loading, android-studio-3.0

[image]

I was using android studio version 3.0. Suddenly after opening my android studio some of class loaded like this. But the whole project runs well. Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: DashboardActivity.java is basically json file saved with .java extension. so file will open like this it's not aa java file.

Comment: how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution,somehow the file got corrupted,i copy the file in a text file,create the class & reload the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

1. copy the code to any text editor
2. delete DashboardActivity.java class
3. create new DashboardActivity.java class under Activity
4. replace the code of DashboardActivity and save